# without selecting how to pass the spinner value

Tags: java, android, spinner

Hi in the below code I have a edit button .If I am click on edit button setting the spinner values to the spinner .

click on edit button spinner value is setting the adapter.

```
 String speclizations = getArguments().getString("speclization_name");
      ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Specializationnames);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinnerSpecialization.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);
            if(spinnerSpecialization.getSelectedItem().equals(0)){

                speclizations = getArguments().getString("speclizations");
                Log.d("salutation_names",salutation_names);

            }else {
                speclizations=spinnerSpecialization.getSelectedItem().toString();
            }
```

Same value I am passing after click on save button I am passing the spinner value without selecting want to pass the same value.but it is throwing an error.

spinner.getslecteditem().toString();//null

Can any one help me how to resolve the issue.

Comment: retrieve  0th position value

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya can you help me

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            if(spinner.getslecteditem().equals(0))
            {
              //Display a toast message to select any values from the Spinner
            }
            else {
               str = spinner.getslecteditem().toString();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Comment: First, you should set the spinner using adapter. Then only you can access item selected by the user.

Comment: Yeah, I saw your post. I have updated my answer, take a look.

Comment: Onitemselction method .But I am not selecting any item in that spinner

Comment: Which value do you want to get without selecting a value from the spinner?

Comment: String speclizations = getArguments().getString("speclization_name"); nothing is selected want to pass this value .if there are selecting from spinner want to getselecteditem of the spinner

Comment: @ did you got the solution

Comment: I didn't understand your question.

Comment: if i am not selecting any item from spinner what is default value set to the spinner want to pass that value.otherwise want to pass getselecteditem from spinner

Comment: you need not set it to the spinner, you can assign the value to the variable.

Comment: 1. Remove that else part.         2. Add setOnItemSelectedListener() and paste speclizations=spinnerSpecialization.getSelectedItem().toString(); inside it